# Problemas com SELECT com 2 WHEREs

Tags: c#, sql, select, where

Estou com um problema meio amador aqui.
Não estou conseguindo fazer este `SELECT` a partir de 2 CONDIÇÕES, e não consigo encontrar o ERRO! Alguém por favor, me dê uma luz aí!

Segue o Código:

```
OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection();
Con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnection;

Con.Open();
OleDbCommand Cmm = new OleDbCommand();

Cmm.CommandText = "SELECT CodAutomaticProd, DescProd, BrandCod FROM tbProdutos WHERE ModelProd LIKE '%" + txtModel.Text + "%' AND YearProd LIKE '%" + txtYear.Text + " %' ";

Cmm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Cmm.Connection = Con;

OleDbDataReader DR;
DR = Cmm.ExecuteReader();

listBox1.Items.Clear();

while (DR.Read())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(DR.GetInt32(0) + " - " + DR.GetString(1) + " -    " + DR.GetString(2));
}
```

O código roda perfeitamente dentro do BANCO, e está dentro do `TRY` que não indica ERRO pelo "Exception".

Comment: Qual seria o erro? Você não devia estar concatenando `string`s. Devia estar usando parâmetros.

Comment: O seu select está funcionando se rodado diretamente no banco? O seu código está dentro de um bloco try/catch? Se sim verifique o que a mensagem do catch diz e poste na sua pergunta.

Comment: Cigano, o programa não está indicando erro propriamente dito, 
ele apenas não traz as informações.

Provavelmente é algo a partir do AND, pois quando coloca apenas 1 condilçao a "ModelProd" ele traz as informações perfeitamente.

Comment: Veja sobre [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Comment: E também isso: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem um espaço em branco na formação da string antes de finalizar o último LIKE

txtYear.Text + "(**aqui**) %'

Comment: Putz Daniel !
Era isso mesmo cara! rodou perfeito ! 

Muito Obrigado brother ! ; )

Comment: huauhauha, de nada, cara. ;)

Answer (score 7):

A maneira correta de fazer isso é usando parametrização. Desta forma, você pode injetar código SQL indesejado na sua consulta:

```
Cmm.CommandText = "SELECT CodAutomaticProd, DescProd, BrandCod FROM tbProdutos WHERE ModelProd LIKE '%@ModelProd%' AND YearProd LIKE '%@YearProd%' ";
Cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ModelProd", txtModel.Text));
Cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@YearProd", txtYear.Text));
```

Comment: Muito Bom também, Cigado, deu certo e ficou mais organizado !
Obrigado !

Comment: Não só ficou mais organizado, como é uma prática mais segura pro teu sistema. Evite usar concatenação de string pra montar a tua instrução select. Evitando assim dores de cabeça como o SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Espaço em branco " %' "

Like deve ser '%valor%'